# Replication of SQL Server between two different servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

Can any One help me in replication between two different server of MS SQL Server? Or some one share with me document with step by step process with images.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find some tutorials in [Replication Tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337389.aspx) on MSDN.  There are several other tutorials online you can find with a quick search.

If you have specific questions you can post them back here.